# How can I check if a html popover is open?

Tags: html, popover

With the new [popover API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API), is there a way to check with JavaScript if the popover is currently open?

```html
<button popovertarget="pop">Trigger the popover</button>
<div popover id="pop">This is the popover!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no dedicated JavaScript API to check the state of a popover. However, the [`matches` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) can be used in combination with the [`:popover-open` CSS pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:popover-open) to achieve the same result:

```js
const popover = document.querySelector('#pop');
const state = document.querySelector('#popover-state');

popover.addEventListener('toggle', () => {
    const isOpen = popover.matches(':popover-open');
    state.innerHTML = isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed';
});
```

```html
<button popovertarget="pop">Trigger the popover</button>
<div popover id="pop">This is the popover!</div>
<p>The popover is <span id="popover-state">closed</span></p>
```

Another approach is using the [`beforetoggle` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforetoggle_event):

```js
const popover = document.querySelector('#pop');
const state = document.querySelector('#popover-state');

popover.addEventListener('beforetoggle', (event) => {
    state.innerHTML = event.newState; // 'open' or 'closed'
});
```

```html
<button popovertarget="pop">Trigger the popover</button>
<div popover id="pop">This is the popover!</div>
<p>The popover is <span id="popover-state">closed</span></p>
```

Answer originally posted by Luke Warlow and westbrookj on Discord https://discord.com/channels/714891843556606052/961979349639245854/1167046293751873536

Comment: I was about to paste this in your answer `const popover = document.querySelector('#pop'); setInterval(() => {
  const isOpen = popover.matches(':popover-open'); console.log(isOpen)},1000)`